# c#, Асинхронная загрузка файла

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, async-await, windows-phone-8.1

Доброго времени суток.
У меня имеется коллекция неких объектов.

При запуске приложения мне необходимо загрузить данные из файла в коллекцию.

Десериализация - наше все, но у меня встала проблема с асинхронным запросом к файлу.

Каким образом мне загрузить файл в таком стиле?

History = LoadFile("History.xml");

```
static async void LoadObject(StorageFile Path)
    {
        using (var readerStream = await Path.OpenStreamForReadAsync())
        {
            var Serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(?????);

            try
            {
                ????? = (??????)Serializer.Deserialize(readerStream);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                ShowMessage(string.Format("Exception: {0}\n{1}", e.InnerException, e.Message));
            }
        }
    }
```

Примерно таким образом у меня организован метод загрузки.

Comment: Вопрос-то в чем?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для начала, вы не можете десериализировать неизвестный тип данных. Тем более, вам нужно какой-то тип возвращать из метода. Так что сделаем метод обобщённы, после этого сразу понятно, какой тип сериализатора использовать:

```
static async Task<T> LoadObject<T>(StorageFile path)
{
    using (var readerStream = await path.OpenStreamForReadAsync())
    {
        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));

        try
        {
            return (T)serializer.Deserialize(readerStream);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            //ShowMessage(string.Format("Exception: {0}\n{1}", e.InnerException, e.Message));
            throw new DeserializationFailedException("Cannot deserialize", e);
        }
    }
}
```

Тип при вызове функции нужно указывать, разумеется, тот же, что вы указывали при *сериализации*.

Изменения:

- Отделяем контент от представления. Функции десериализации негоже показывать сообщения в UI
- У нас есть возвращаемый тип, при ошибке выбрасываем кастомное исключение. Внешнему коду, да, нужно ловить его. Подавление ошибок всё равно было неверно, приложению **не имеет право** быть всё равно, случилась ли ошибка.
- Локальные переменные принято называть со строчной буквы.

---

Если загрузка слишком медленная (например, файл слишком большой), можно выгрузить десериализацию в отдельный поток:

```
return await Task.Run(() => (T)serializer.Deserialize(readerStream));
```

Comment: Верно ли вы описали сигнатуру метода?
Может быть таким образом?
`static async Task<T> LoadObject<T>(StorageFile path)`

Comment: @bodynar: Точно, исправил ответ

Comment: что-то я немного затупил - каким образом пользоваться данным методом?
Я изначально предполагал, что будет метод, которому я буду отправлять StorageFile и в ответ буду получать десериализованный объект.
`History = LoadObject<MyHistory>(Path);` В таком стиле.

Comment: Просто с Task ни разу не работал ранее

Comment: @bodynar: Ну, у вас же async-метод, так что через await: `History = await LoadObject<MyHistory>(Path)`.